# Show Loading Gif On Click Submit Button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, loading, form-submit

i am using upload picture plugin for my website and when users click on submit on mobile devices they can't see any progress so they click submit button again and again and i get too many same posts, i want to show loading gif image when they click on submit button , this is the plugin form

```
<form id="usp_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

\\rest code here

<input type="submit" class="usp-submit" id="user-submitted-post" name="user-submitted-post" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Submit Post', 'usp'); ?>">
</form>
```

and i have tried this found on stack but it didn't work

```
<img src="https://www.punjabidharti.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-email/images/loading.gif" id="img" style="display:none"/ >

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#usp_form').submit(function() {
    $('#img').css('visibility', 'visible');
});</script>
```

and here is my upload pictures url

```
https://www.punjabidharti.com/upload-pictures/
```

hope you can help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a div with `display: none` inside your layout file and make it `display:block` when needed

```
<div style="z-index: 5000; display:none;" id="loadingDiv">
    <table style="margin: 0px auto;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:200px;" align="center"><img src="https://www.punjabidharti.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-email/images/loading.gif" alt="loading image"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

$('#usp_form').submit(function() {
    // javascript way
    document.getElementById("loadingDiv").style.display = 'block';
    // jquery way
    $('#loadingDiv').show();  
});
```

**Update**

```
layout level files can be any of following:

layout.html
index.html
header.html
footer.html
```

You may try another gif image for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBLb3.gif

Comment: I use same snippet from years ! check if it is loaded properly in your DOM ?

Comment: Do not forget to put the div in a top level file.

Comment: it works but loading gif is not spinning while image uploading

Comment: I tested it with your image, spinning properly. Could you hard reload your page CTRL+SHIFT+R and see what happens ?

Comment: on desktop its working properly but on mobile its not spinning

Comment: Can't guess the reason of mobile but, I have added mine gif image in answer, you can choose that one as it is bigger.

Comment: i was testing that on safari in iphone but on Android And Webview App for ios and Android it works, so thank you so much,

Comment: Happy to help !

Comment: Attached is a very interesting solution that has a similar effect. For people who want to try it, they can consult the code and the step-by-step implementation instructions (which are also very easy and short to follow) of Replacing Submit Button with 'Loading Image' that works perfectly. It is highly recommended. I was in a similar situation looking for a way to implement a preloader after the submit button. It's worth a try. NB: credits go to willmaster.com - Here is the link:  https://www.willmaster.com/library/manage-forms/replacing-submit-button-with-loading-image.php

Answer (score 0):

You've added 'style="display:none"' in your img but in code you're doing:

```
$('#img').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

You should do:

```
$('#img').css('display', 'inline-block');
```